# Drawing rectangle/ polygon/ line/ circle using right mouse click using Leaflet Editable

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to use [Leaflet Editable](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable) to draw some rectangle/ circle on the map. 
I am wondering is there a way that I create rectangle/circle using right click and drag to instead of using the left mouse click?